# object DataFrame is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Tags: apache-spark

I `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` in my scala file, than use `sbt` to compile, the error was `object DataFrame is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql`

Searched for some solutions in the Internet, it seems that the problem is spark version is too old. But I am using the newest version(2.1.1), so it is weird.

In REPL, when I `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`, there is no error.

My function is like this:

```
def test(df: DataFrame): Unit={
    ....
}
```

When I define this function in REPL, it is fine, but when I compile it using sbt, the error is `not found: type DataFrame`.

My build.sbt:

```
name := "Hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

Anyone can help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the dependencies in your sbt.build.

Comment: Add `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1"` to your dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need both spark-core and spark-sql to work with Dataframe

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1"
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My god, it works!!! I am really new to spark, have spent several hours on it.. Thank you very much!